# How to resize components within JFrame when JFrame is resized?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, absolutelayout

RESOLVED

I've looked around for a while now and I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

I have lots of components within my JFrame and I am able to resize my JFrame. When I resize the JFrame I want the internal components to resize along with the JFrame, but instead they stay exactly where they were when the GUI was first run.

How can I fix this problem? Is there a value I'm not setting somewhere or what?

Edit:
Also, I'm not using any layout manager.

```
getContentPane().setLayout(null);
```

Comment: Search the forum on this as this is a common question and has been answered many times, all the same: Use good layout managers that will do the resizing for you. The layout manager tutorial will show you how.

Comment: What layout do you think works best? FlowLayout doesn't do it, I checked that one.

Comment: There is no one that works best, and you need to learn them all. Often you use many on one GUI, nesting them in nested JPanels.

Comment: *"Is there a value I'm not setting somewhere or what?"* - Yes, the layout manager

Comment: Fixed it. Using a BorderLayout did what I wanted. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You state:

> Edit: Also, I'm not using any layout manager. getContentPane().setLayout(null);

That's your problem. You should almost never use null layout. It is *much* easier to use and maintain a gui that uses layout managers in a smart way. Read the [layout manager tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) as they can help.